# lu decomposition of submatrix

Tags: matrix-calculus

We have a matrix $A$ and $A'$ is a submatrix of $A$.
first we make LU decomposition of $A$,  $$A = L_a \cdot U_a.$$
Now, I want to make LU decomposition of $A'$, $$A' = L_a' \cdot U_a'.$$
is there any relation between $L_a, U_a, L_a',U_a'$? Maybe some similar operations between the two LU decompositions?

Comment: Is $A'$ just an arbitrary submatrix? Or is it the leading submatrix?

Comment: A' is an arbitrary submatrix of A.

Answer (score 1):

For an arbitrary submatrix of $A$, the $LU$ decomposition may not exist. This is because $LU$ decompositions only exist for invertible matrices, and arbitrary submatrices of a matrix need not be invertible. Therefore, a general formula will not be possible.

Comment: Could you please give me some reference of this? I've a very similar problem and any reference might be useful

Comment: @user3810266 Any standard textbook that covers the LU decomposition...

Comment: I will have a look thank you, anyway my problem is summarized in the following question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1047983/lu-decomposition-for-the-solution-of-two-linear-systems#1047983  Maybe you want to have a look at it