# LU Decomposition for the solution of two linear systems

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Let's say I have the following linear system:
\begin{equation}
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
S&&L^{T}&&A^{T}&&0\\
L&&0&&0&&0\\
A&&0&&0&&B\\
0&&0&&B^{T}&&0
\end{array}
\right]
\cdot
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
u\\
p\\
\lambda \\
u_{p}
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
f\\
0\\
0 \\
0
\end{array}
\right]
\end{equation}

Let's say I solve it by using a LU decomposition, it is well known that if I have the same system but with a different RHS ($f_{1}$ instead of $f$) I can solve the new system using the same LU decomposition making the solution very fast.

My question is, what if I have a smaller version of the system, for example:
\begin{equation}
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
S&&L^{T}\\
L&&0
\end{array}
\right]
\cdot
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
u\\
p
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
f\\
0\\
\end{array}
\right]
\end{equation}

that is exactly the same system eliminating $\lambda$ and $u_{p}$ from the unknowns, Can I relate the LU decomposition of this new system, to the LU decomposition of the bigger system so that the solution of this sub-problem can be fast?

In practice what I would like to do is to avoid solving a big system and then again a smaller version of it, but i'm looking for a shortcut that speeds up the computation.